# Impersonate room in EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am new to Exchange server. I would like to create meeting via EWS. My goal is to book meeting on a room and later pull all the meetings for a specific room. Just knowing the room identifier.

Is it possible to impersonate room in meeting creation or it is just enough to add room as a participant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A room shouldn't be the organizer of a Meeting so there should be no need to try to impersonate it (by default room accounts are disabled so you can't impersonate a disabled account). The only person you should impersonate is the Organizer of the appointment add the Room as a resource of the Meeting your creating and then send the request to the meeting room mailbox and let Auto-accept handle the rest.

Cheers
Glen

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="
http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://sc
hemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xml
soap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    <t:TimeZoneContext>
      <t:TimeZoneDefinition Name="(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney" Id="AUS Eastern Standard Time">
        <t:Periods>
          <t:Period Bias="-P0DT11H0M0.0S" Name="Daylight" Id="Dlt/1" />
          <t:Period Bias="-P0DT10H0M0.0S" Name="Standard" Id="Std/1" />
          <t:Period Bias="-P0DT11H0M0.0S" Name="Daylight" Id="Dlt/2008" />
          <t:Period Bias="-P0DT10H0M0.0S" Name="Standard" Id="Std/2008" />
        </t:Periods>
        <t:TransitionsGroups>
          <t:TransitionsGroup Id="0">
            <t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:To Kind="Period">Dlt/1</t:To>
              <t:TimeOffset>P0DT2H0M0.0S</t:TimeOffset>
              <t:Month>10</t:Month>
              <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
              <t:Occurrence>-1</t:Occurrence>
            </t:RecurringDayTransition>
            <t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:To Kind="Period">Std/1</t:To>
              <t:TimeOffset>P0DT3H0M0.0S</t:TimeOffset>
              <t:Month>3</t:Month>
              <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
              <t:Occurrence>-1</t:Occurrence>
            </t:RecurringDayTransition>
          </t:TransitionsGroup>
          <t:TransitionsGroup Id="1">
            <t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:To Kind="Period">Dlt/2008</t:To>
              <t:TimeOffset>P0DT2H0M0.0S</t:TimeOffset>
              <t:Month>10</t:Month>
              <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
              <t:Occurrence>1</t:Occurrence>
            </t:RecurringDayTransition>
            <t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:To Kind="Period">Std/2008</t:To>
              <t:TimeOffset>P0DT3H0M0.0S</t:TimeOffset>
              <t:Month>4</t:Month>
              <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
              <t:Occurrence>1</t:Occurrence>
            </t:RecurringDayTransition>
          </t:TransitionsGroup>
        </t:TransitionsGroups>
        <t:Transitions>
          <t:Transition>
            <t:To Kind="Group">0</t:To>
          </t:Transition>
          <t:AbsoluteDateTransition>
            <t:To Kind="Group">1</t:To>
            <t:DateTime>2007-12-31T13:00:00.000Z</t:DateTime>
          </t:AbsoluteDateTransition>
        </t:Transitions>
      </t:TimeZoneDefinition>
    </t:TimeZoneContext>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
      <m:Items>
        <t:CalendarItem>
          <t:Subject>Meeting</t:Subject>
          <t:Start>2016-03-01T12:33:17.185+11:00</t:Start>
          <t:End>2016-03-01T13:33:17.185+11:00</t:End>
          <t:RequiredAttendees>
            <t:Attendee>
              <t:Mailbox>
                <t:EmailAddress>attendee@mailbox.com</t:EmailAddress>
              </t:Mailbox>
            </t:Attendee>
          </t:RequiredAttendees>
          <t:Resources>
            <t:Attendee>
              <t:Mailbox>
                <t:EmailAddress>room@mailbox.com</t:EmailAddress>
              </t:Mailbox>
            </t:Attendee>
          </t:Resources>
        </t:CalendarItem>
      </m:Items>
    </m:CreateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you please pro provide me with an example of SOAP request with room added as resource. Thank you.